# Append JQuery with backbone

Tags: jquery, json, backbone.js, append

I'm working with Backbone and Dyson for simulate a API. I'm trying show the results of the JSON but I have the error: Uncaught TypeError: self.template is not a function.

```
ReservaCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
initialize: function () {
    if (Session.get('authenticated') && Session.get('authenticated') !== false) {
        this.template = _.template($('#divReservaTpl').html(), {});

        //Vector donde almacenamos las subvistas que corresponden a las reservas
        this.subViewsReservas = [];
        //Instancia de la vista de la paginación
        this.paginacionVista = new PaginacionReservasView({
            collection: this.collection,
            el: '.paginacionReservas',
            reservasPagina: 5,
        });
        //Instancia de la vista del buscador (simulamando los datos del servidor que corresponden a la colección oficinas )
        this.buscadorVista = new BuscadorView({
            el: 'div.buscador-reservas',
            collection: new OficinasCollection(oficinas),
        });
    }
    else {
    }
},
render: function () {
    var self = this;
    //var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    self.$('.contenedor-reservas').empty();
    self.collection.each(function (reserva, index) {
      console.log(reserva);
      console.log(index);

        self.$('.contenedor-reservas').append(self.template({'data': reserva.toJSON()}));

    });

    this.collection.each(function (reserva, index) {
        self.subViewsReservas.push(new ReservaView({
            el: '#' + reserva.get('Idreserva'),
            model: reserva
        }));
    });


    this.collection.each(function (reserva, index) {
        //Limite de la paginacion 5 limite arbitrario
        if (index < 5) {
            //Lo Marcamos como visible y actualiazamos la paginación
            self.collection.get(reserva.get('Idreserva')).set({'Visibilidad': true});
        }
    });

    this.paginacionVista.render();

    return this;
},
```

});

**Value of the reservaJSON():**

```
{"Idreserva":"1","Idcliente":403,"Idtarifa":3,"Idgrupo":3,"Bono":"WG5000218E","BonoAgencia":"7741124","Fecha":"2015-02-17 11:49:09","Dropoffdate":"2015-02-17 11:49:09","Pickupdate":"2015-02-17 11:49:09","Grupo":"XXX","reserva_status":3,"Estado":3,"status":true}
```

Comment: You're setting `this.template` *conditionally*. In other words, as you have things written `this.template` isn't guaranteed to be defined by the time `render` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One scenario where this could occur is when the condition

```
if (Session.get('authenticated') && Session.get('authenticated') !== false)
```

fails.

In such case, `this.template = _.template($('#divReservaTpl').html(), {});` won't execute and `template` property won't be present in view.

I suggest having the [template](http://backbonejs.org/#View-template) property in the view definition itself as suggested in the documentation:

```
ReservaCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
 initialize: function () 
 },
 template: _.template($('#divReservaTpl').html()),
 render: function(){}
});
```

You can then choose whether to `render` the view or not based on conditions safely.

Another scenario in which this error might occur is when the context in which `render` method executed (`this`) refers to something else other than the view.

Comment: First I want give you the thanks for your answer. With your solution "Template is not defined" but if I put inside of Render, all working ok.

Comment: @JordiSalom yes it'll work, but `_.template()` needs to run every time when you call `render()` method, if you define the `template` property as shown in the answer, it'll be called only once when the view is created. You can use `this.template({})` as many times as you want later without executing `_.template()` unnecessarily :)

Answer (score -1):

I think that you are loosing the context, when you do the

```
var self = this;
```

Try to put the code below in the initialize function.

If you do the var self = this in initialize this will referer the object View but if you do it in the function it will referer the function!